# SQL Server Deadlock Log Entries

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, deadlock

We're analysing a deadlock situation on a SQL Server 2005 database and have set the trace flags 1204 and 1222.

In the resulting logs we're seeing the following line repeatedly:

"Log Viewer could not read information for this log entry. Cause: Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values."

Can anyone tell me what's likely to be causing this? There's nothing particularly wrong with the queries that I can see (they're generated by Hibernate so are a bit messy and full of aliases but are fundamentally sound).

Is it something I need to worry about or something that can be ignored?

Answer (score 4):

Something wrong with the viewer (looks like the bug in SSMS), but you always can open ERRORLOG in any other viewer, such as notepad and get exactly the same info

Answer (score 3):

Probably just a client (SSMS) issue rendering the error log.

[xp_readerrorlog](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/using-xp_readerrorlog-in-sql-server-2005) will make it easier to parse the deadlock entries from the error log and bypass the display bug.